# Replacing character in position

Tags: string-manipulation

I'm trying to use Mathematica to make some work on binary data, and I'm missing something.

Consider the string `"111"`. I want to flip the last bit to become `"110"`. My guess would be to use `StringReplacePart`, but I'm struggling to achieve this:

```
StringReplacePart["111", "0", 3]  (* returns "0" *)
```

What is the function for replacing a single character at a given position?

Comment: You need `{3, 3}` as the last argument... that's the only documented form. It looks like using just `3` is equivalent to `{1, 3}`, but is undocumented.

Comment: -.-' I needed it in a middle position and because, strangely enough, `StringReplacePart["111", "0", -1]` works, I assumed the notation was consistent. Thanks @rm-rf, feel free to add an answer.

Comment: The last part of my answer explains why `-1` worked differently. It seems like for negative indices, it is equivalent to `{n, -1}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documented form of [`StringReplacePart`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringReplacePart.html) is

```
StringReplacePart["string", "snew", {m, n}]
```

where the replacement is done from positions `m` through `n`. In your case, you would need `{3, 3}`:

```
StringReplacePart["111", "0", {3, 3}]
(* "110" *)
```

You can also use `-1` as the index for the last element (useful when the string length is unknown).

---

Using only an integer `n` as the last argument doesn't seem to be documented, but from a quick test, it appears to be the same as `{1, n}` for positive `n` and `{n, -1}` for negative `n`.